# Pass data/object between assemblies in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

The Windows Phone 7 project I'm working on has 2 UIs, and a core 'engine' of functionality with some pages that are common. I'd like my user interface to pass an object into one of these common pages in the core assembly.

Currently I can navigate to pages in the core assembly from the UI assembly. However, it is my understanding that each assembly has it's own Isolated storage, is that correct?

If I can share Isolated storage, I can use that, I'm just not sure how to get the two assemblies to use it together.

What's the best practice?

I tried googling this: 'wp7 pass object between assemblies'

More Info:
This would be 1 application with two assemblies. Something like this:

CustomerUI (project)
- MainPage.xaml
- App.xaml

CoreFuncs (project)
- CustomerData.cs
- EditCustomer.xaml

SalesRepUI (project)
- MainPage.xaml
- App.xaml

Both CustomerUI and SalesRepUI would use the EditCustomer page and customerData object. So, from MainPage a CustomerData object is instantiated, then a user could click 'Edit User' which would navigate to the common EditCustomer.xaml page. We would want to pass in the already instantiated CustomerData object. (For the purpose of this discussion...)

Comment: Sorry, Sorry, I found what I wanted, I was thinking too hard.

`PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["keyName"] = object;` was exactly what I wanted.

Not sure if its the best way, but for me, it works. Just throw my settings class or whatever in there, and catch it on the other side in the page.xaml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, Sorry, I found what I wanted, I was thinking too hard. 
`PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["keyName"] = object;` was exactly what I wanted. Not sure if its the best way, but for me, it works. Just throw my settings class or whatever in there, and catch it on the other side in the page.xaml code.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, there is one Isolated storage per application, not per assembly. So you can try pass your objects through it if you like.

Answer (score 1):

It depends are these two separate applications or two assemblies?

Isolated storage is isolated around the running application.  This means each app has its own storage that cannot be accessed from a different app.  The only ways to share data between two apps are:

1. A WebService/or TCP service in 7.5:  You would upload the data from one app and download the data into a separate application.
2. User performed tasks: Copy and Paste/Sending an Email

However if this is just one application you will be able to access the isolated storage between the assemblies just by reading and writing to the files.  The only thing to be aware of is file locking, make sure you close files any before you attempt to read from them from a separate dll/assembly.

Comment: Hmm... okay, that would be great.  
However, I am using the App.xaml.cs class for isolated storage, I get values like this `return (Application.Current as UIAppName.App).ValueName;`. The UIAppName will reference the CoreClasses objection, but can CoreClasses get to the App data from UIAppName?

Comment: So, how about this, I have MainPage.xaml in UIApp which can read values from App.xaml. The user then gets navigated to CommonPage.xaml in the CoreFuncs assembly. When MainPage.xaml loads, I'd like to read the settings into an area where CommonPage.xaml can get to them. I was thinking about a adding a settings class to CoreFuncs, somthing like CoreFuncs.appSettings, that CommonPage could write to. Am I on the right track?

Comment: If Create your own class for settings and serialize/deserialize it to isolated storage.  Link on Serialization: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813 Link on Isolated Storage:  http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files  You could have this class replicated in each assembly... OR you could create a class library that is referenced by both assemblies

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Messenger class in the MVVM Light toolkit:
http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx

Both of your assemblies can reference a single shared assembly; that assembly can contain a type that you use to hold data passed via the messenger.